# Proof by simple induction, question concerning the inductive step

Tags: induction

Sorry in advance for posting a picture instead of the text, I'm not familiar with Latex yet...

My question is...

Why do we get: 
4n^2 + 12n + 7 = 4((n − 1) + 1)^2 + 12((n − 1) + 1) + 7

And not this: 
4n^2 + 12n + 7 = 4(n+1)^2 + 12(n+1) + 7

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0EP0.png)

Comment: The first equation is trivially true since $(n-1)+1=n$.  The second expression isn't set equal to anything, so I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry I just corrected it - It should just be n instead of k.
I originally assumed a fresh witness n = k, but I left it out here to make it more simple.

Comment: I thought that when you add n+1 to 4n^2 it would be 4(n+1)^2, but that is not true I guess?

Comment: The second equation is obviously false.  Just take $n=0$ for example.

Comment: Because $n=(n-1)+1$ and $n\neq n+1$.

Comment: Looking at the attached picture, the writer there is a bit careless.  The argument shows that $P(n-1)\implies P(n)$ and  NOT $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ as stated.  Of course, logically it is the same thing...but it is expressed poorly there.

Comment: For the LaTeX: literally wrap what you've written so far in dollar signs, and you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The induction step should be "Assume that $P(n-1)$ holds, and then we show that $P(n)$ holds". This is an inaccuracy in the proof. Also, you should never say "Suppose we know that $P(n)$ is true", just say "Suppose that $P(n)$ is true". (That is the induction hypothesis, not the fact that we know it...)

Comment: I thought the inductive step in a simple induction generally was to prove k+1 holds when having assumed a fresh witness of n = k.
While the inductive step in strong induction often was to prove that p(n-1) holds for p(i) where i < n. 

Is this a misunderstanding?

Comment: There are different forms of induction. Also, it doesn't matter if you prove $P(n-1)\Rightarrow P(n)$ or $P(n)\Rightarrow P(n+1)$, just be consistent with your choice.

Comment: The part where this assignment doesn't make sense for me, is that they want to show that P(n) implies P(n+1) and then write "4((n-1+1)^2" instead of "4(n+1)^2".

Comment: That is exactly what I put in my answer, please read it again. It is indeed an inaccuracy.

Comment: Just to clarify that I understand it correctly. 
We CAN choose to say that P(n) implies P(n+1) is true instead of P(n-1), but then we would have "4(n+1)^2" instead of "4((n-1)+1)^2)"?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Could you accept my answer? Thank you.